# Is flair still new? You can probably remove the <sup style="background-color:yellow">new</sup> on user pages now

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, profile-page, flair

If you go to your user page it still says get the NEW flair...probably ok to replace that little yellow box now
[image: flair is new]

Comment: They also put the internet on tape drives now, the 3.5 is so yesterday. No more swapping disks.

Comment: I print the internet out each morning, and read it on the bus

Comment: According [to Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83232/flair-link-indicated-as-new/83233#83233): *There is a 10% chance this will appear at any given time; it's just to make sure everyone is seeing it.*

Comment: Even if a `[discussion]` could be `[status-completed]`, then still that tag can only be set by moderators (and your `[status-is-completed]` seems confusing to me).