# Flair Link indicated as new?

Tags: support, profile-page, flair

The got flair? link on Meta has a highlighted `new` next to it.

[image: Meta Flairz]

It isn't new any more and doesn't appear on other sites (SO, WebApps, Programmers)

Can it be removed as I keep thinking there are new flair goodies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 10% chance this will appear at any given time; it's just to make sure everyone is seeing it.

Comment: But: no changes [since September 2010](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/), right?